# What is wind "CALM"?

Tags: wind, meteorology

What is the exact criteria for wind speed to be considered "CALM".
Different countries might have different values and i do not mind getting answers from those. But an answer from an ICAO annex would be prefered.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wind "CALM" means a wind speed less than 0.5m/s (1 kt) according to ICAO Annex 3, Appendix 3:

> 4.1.5.2    In local routine and special reports and in METAR and SPECI:
>
> ...
>
> d)  when a wind speed of less than 0.5m/s (1 kt) is reported, it shall be indicated as calm;

Before Amendment 75 of ICAO Annex 3 this read:

> d)  when a wind speed of less than 2 km/h (1 kt) is reported, it shall be indicated as calm;

See also Annex 3:

- Appendix 5, recommendation 1.2.1
- Attachment C

---

The FAA, in their Order JO 7110.65X (Air Traffic Control), defines a limit of 3 knots.

> 2−6−3.  REPORTING WEATHER CONDITIONS
>
> ....
>
> b. Describe  the  wind  as  calm  when  the  wind velocity is less than three knots.